# Calculate PRODUCT of a sub-range in a Google Sheets range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a range with Type for columns and Level for rows.
I need to find the PRODUCT of a sub-range which is from Level 1 to the given Level of given Type.

So far I tried to find the position of the starting and ending cells of sub-range by using:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A1:N21,2,MATCH(R4,A1:N1,0)))

=CELL("address",index(A1:N21,R3+1,match(R4,A1:N1,0)))
```

Then I think about using CONCATENATE to give the range address but it returns 0.

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byIjDzHZE6s5N1PcN9yvSeC51bm9NVVC1tc1gjQQLHA/edit#gid=0

Comment: What is the product you want to perform, a specific cell from the range after you specify the row and column with another cell (that you also have specified the row and column)? Also, when I access your sheet I can see that you already performed a couple of products, did you already resolved your issue? Thanks !

Comment: Yes a range in my example table. I found one solution but it is quite long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you don't need such a long formula. Index returns a cell reference, so you can do something in the form of index(...startrow,startcol):index(...endrow,endcol) like this:

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(A1:N21,2,MATCH(R4,A1:N1,0)):INDEX(A1:N21,R3+1,MATCH(R4,A1:N1,0)))
```

[image]

Even shorter is offset:

```
=PRODUCT(offset(A1,1,MATCH(R4,A1:N1,0)-1,R3,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution by using the reference to the range:

> `=PRODUCT(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(A1:N21,2,MATCH(R4,A1:N1,0)))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX(A1:N21,R3+1,MATCH(R4,A1:N1,0)))))`

However, it is quite long. I would like to have a better solution in the case.