# Get sub-range address from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my other question, I can get the sub-range of a range by using INDIRECT and CELL: [Calculate PRODUCT of a sub-range in a Google Sheets range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208151/calculate-product-of-a-sub-range-in-a-google-sheets-range)

However, If I use the formula in another sheet, it will show #REF!:

> Error
>   Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'Sheet1!$I$2:Sheet1!$I$17'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

I know that the format should be Sheet1!$I$2:$I$17 but I wonder how can I do that?

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byIjDzHZE6s5N1PcN9yvSeC51bm9NVVC1tc1gjQQLHA/edit#gid=462032657

It could be better if I can use named range for this.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. Do you want to calculate the product of a subrange or the address of a subrange? And what exactly are oyu trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you get this `Sheet1!$I$17` you might enclose it in:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(..., "[^!]+$")
```

This will cut off sheet's name from the cell name.

But you've got [a nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61211705/279806) in that question where you can use `OFFSET` and forget about string manipulations for `INDIRECT`. And it will still work when you copy it to different sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidy little solution that i've left for you on Sheet1 in cell R9:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PRODUCT(B2:N21^((A2:A21<=R3)*(B1:N1=R4))))
```

Cheers!